# Observable gives multiple values

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an observable which sends me Socket Data

```js
getMessages() {

let observable = new Observable(observer => {


  this.sp.socket.on('new_msg_server', (data) => {
    observer.next(data);
  });

return observable;
  });
}
```

I am subscribing to the observable like below

```
getMessages().subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data);
})
```

I am expecting the `data` to be the latest data. But I get all previous values when logging `data`

Is this normal behaviour of an observable ? Does it always return the whole observable history ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your observable the wrong way. I tried to explain why its wrong but it came out hard to understand so instead just try this something like this:

```
getMessages() {

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.sp.socket.on('new_msg_server', (data) => {
            observer.next(data);
        });

        // You should do some error handling here, not sure what kind of socket you are using, but something like this 
        this.socket.on('error', (error) => {
            observer.error(error);
        });

        return () => {
            // Close connection and clean up here
            this.sp.socket.close(); // or what works for you..
        };
    });
}
```